# Insert new Spatial Reference System (SRID) into SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, spatial, arcgis, coordinate-systems, srid

**Sorry for the long introduction before my question, but I have seen it answerd a few times in a way that does not help me precisely because of lack of contest. For those of you who are willing to read until the end and try to aid me, I really appreciate that. Here it goes...**

I work in the database department of a power distribution company in Brazil, which uses a custom Datum created out of the unification of UTM zones 23S and 24S based on the Datum SAD69.

I use SQL Server 2012 ([SQL Server Specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XZmW.png)) and ArcMap 10.4.01 ([ArcGIS Specifications](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaXl2.png)) to manage an isolated GIS (Don't know if I made myself clear here, but what I mean is I am de DBA of such database and no one else has access to it)  made up data retrievd from an Oracle 11g online database and my DB is updated everyday at noon via ArcMap, which is connected to both databases and acts as a bridge between the two.

Here is the thing: When I import data into ArcGIS from the Oracle DB, it recognizes the custom Datum with no problem, as I already imported this custom coordinate system into ArcGIS. But when I transfer this data to SQL Server, it loses the spatial reference. As a consequence, When I try to project spatial data from SQL Server in ArcMap, it does not and I have to set it manually, which is a problem because I do it dozens of times everyday, including via script to automate some procedures I have to do. But, when I import spatial data from SQL Server which uses some comertial Spatial Reference, like SIRGAS2000, it recognizes with no problem.

**I cannot edit data stored in SQL Server via ArcGIS because I do not have a ArcServer license. Therefore, I cannot use/create an Interprise Geodatabase, which is one way I thought I could overcome this situation.**

So far, the only way I could think of solving this problem is inserting a new Spatial Rerference into SQL Server. **I know SRID in SQL Server is practically useless because it dosen't support transformations**, but that´s the case only when I am using the SQL Server alone. In this case, as I am using multiple platforms, it becomes very relevant.

So, is there a way to insert a new Spatial Reference and SRID into SQL Server? If not, can anyone think of another solution for my problem?

Feel free to ask anything I might have left out and thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi Luiz, I added feedback on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-catalog-views/sys-spatial-reference-systems-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15